# MediaPlayer sound NullPointerException

Tags: android, media-player

I have to play a sound when i walk in a Geofence. I wrote this:

```
public class GeofenceService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG_LOG = GeofenceService.class.getName();

private MediaPlayer sound;

public GeofenceService() {
    super("GeofenceService");
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.sneezee);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Inizialmente cerchiamo un errore. Nel caso mostriamo un messaggio di errore
    if(LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
        //Prendiamo il codice dell'errore
        final int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);
        //Mostriamo il messaggio di errore
        Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Errore nel Geofence Service: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Errore nel Geofence Service: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
    }
    //Se tutto è corretto prendiamo le informazioni a proposito
    //del transactionId dell'evento
    else {
        final int transactionId = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
        if(transactionId == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            for(Geofence geofence : geofences) {
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Geofence: " + geofence.getRequestId());
                /*long[] pattern = {0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 500};
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(pattern,-1);*/
                sound.start();
            }
        }
        else if(transactionId == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            for(Geofence geofence : geofences) {
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Geofence: " + geofence.getRequestId());
                /*long[] pattern = {0, 500, 0, 200, 0, 200};
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(pattern,-1);*/
                sound.start();
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "No transactionId into the received Intent");
        }
    }
}
```

Bui i get NullPointerException here:

```
sound = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.sneezee);
```

In addition, Android Studio does not recognize that the file is an audio file. There's
a question mark at his icon. :/

Comment: What type of file is sneezee?

Comment: I have the same thing with mp3 and wav

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the subclass of `IntentService`, the `getBaseContext()` method will return `null`. Therefore, you should create `MediaPlayer` instance not in the constructor but in the `onCreate` method.

```
public GeofenceService() {
    super("GeofenceService");
    // in constructor, `getBaseContext()` will return `null`
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sneezee);
}
```